# Connecting a wired network printer to a wireless router talking to another?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

The scenario:

- Multi-function printer located in copy room - back of building
- MFP has network port
- Existing wireless router near front of building
- Existing wireless router has internet connection (users can connect to this router)
- No possibility to run wire from back to front (distance/cost/logistics are too challenging)

Is it possible to add a wireless router to the MFP so that it can talk to the existing wireless router so that the users can print?

The basic flow would be:

Laptop Wireless -> Wireless Router 1 -> Wireless Router 2 -> MFP Wired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need in this case is to set up a [wireless bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_bridge). Your network would have a configuration like this:

[image]

A lot of home routers can be set up to do this, but in the case you want to use DD-WRT, [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge) is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to get the routers to talk to each other which isn't the easiest thing to do (seeing as they are used to only accept wireless clients and act as AP). However, it's not impossible. You would most likely need to change the firmware on your wireless router to make it look for other routers to connect to.

Check this post out:

http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/how-connect-wireless-router-wireless-router-3119.html